# como criar um diretório no sistema android?

Tags: java, android, mobile

Estou usando o seguinte código para criar um diretório quando o usuário apertar um botão dentro de um fragment, mas ainda não esta funcionando, E não sei o porque.

```
            File dir = new File("/novaPasta");
            try{
                if(dir.mkdir()) {
                    System.out.println("diretorio criado");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("diretorio não criado");
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

e estou usando as seguintes permissões:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

não tenho erro algum no log, somente a mensagem de que o diretório não foi criado

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory() [...]

Comment: [...] ou seja, `new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "novaPasta").mkdir()` deve criar uma pasta chamada "novaPasta" na memória interna

Answer (score -3):

Tente utilizar desta forma:

```java
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "novaPasta").mkdir();
```

Você não especificou o caminho da memória interna.